# Is Machine Learning a part of Data Science?

Tags: machine-learning, big-data

I am having trouble differentiating between Big Data vs Data Science. From what I've understood so far, both are buzzwords for the old statistics job. Where does machine learning fit into this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is Machine Learning a part of Data Science?

No.

> Big Data vs Data Science

Not the same.

Birds and Bird Watching are also not the same.

> Machine learning is a type of artificial intelligence (AI) that provides computers with the ability to learn without being explicitly programmed. Machine learning focuses on the development of computer programs that can teach themselves to grow and change when exposed to new data.
> [What is machine learning? - Definition from WhatIs.com](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/machine-learning)
>
> Big data is a term for data sets that are so large or complex that traditional data processing applications are inadequate to deal with them. Challenges include analysis, capture, data curation, search, sharing, storage, transfer, visualization, querying, updating and information privacy.
> [Big data - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data)
>
> Data science is an interdisciplinary field about processes and systems to extract knowledge or insights from data in various forms, either structured or unstructured, which is a continuation of some of the data analysis fields such as statistics, machine learning, data mining, and predictive analytics
> [Data science - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science)

AI has a long independent history that certainly predates data science.  The AI research field was founded in 1956 at Dartmouth College.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_artificial_intelligence)</sup>

Data Science the buzz word only goes back to Peter Naur in 1960.<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science)</sup> Data Science the independent discipline is even more recent from William S. Cleveland in 2001.<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science)</sup>

Big Data, the buzz word, goes back to somewhere in the 1990's and is suspected to have originated with John Mashey and his work at Silicon Graphics.<sup>[3](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/02/01/the-origins-of-big-data-an-etymological-detective-story/?_r=0)</sup>

Nothing says AI couldn't be used in Data Science or be used on some Big Data but AI had a life of its own long before statisticians realized computers could give them more than spreadsheets.

Answer (score -1):

Data science is a broad term that includes data analytics, data mining, machine learning, and a variety of other related fields. Regression and supervised clustering are two approaches used in machine learning. Data in data science, on the other hand, may or may not come from a machine or a mechanical process.

Data science comprises a wide variety of fields, including data analytics, software engineering, data engineering, machine learning, predictive analytics, data analytics, and more. While Machine learning is the process of extracting data, learning from it, and forecasting future trends for a certain topic using algorithms.